# Scroll To position in react-native-web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, react-native, react-native-web

Not able to scroll to particular position while running react-native code in web.

I am able to scroll to position when i run the same as react-native app on mobile but not in react-native-web.

I tried by using both web and react-native properties on achieving this,But could not find the exact solution.

```
<ScrollView 
  contentOffset = {{x: 0, y: this.state.scrollHeight}} 
  style={{marginBottom: window.innerHeight/5,}} 
  ref="scrollView" 
  onLayout={(e)=> { 
    console.log("ht",e.nativeEvent.layout) 
    this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo({x:0,y:e.nativeEvent.layout.height}) 
    this.setState({ scrollHeight: e.nativeEvent.layout.height }); 
  }} 
  onContentSizeChange={(width, height) => { 
    this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo({ y: this.state.scrollHeight }); 
  }} 
>
```

Let me know ,if anybody have faced same issue and resolved.

Comment: try to set its `scrollTop` property , like `scrollTop = 100`. reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Comment: also , show your code , please

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Nothing much complex in code .its normal scrollview of react-native which i am trying to show on web using react-native-web .

Comment: <ScrollView
          contentOffset = {{x: 0, y: this.state.scrollHeight}}
          style={{marginBottom:  window.innerHeight/5,}}
            ref="scrollView"
            onLayout={(e)=> {
              console.log("ht",e.nativeEvent.layout)
           this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo({x:0,y:e.nativeEvent.layout.height})
              this.setState({ scrollHeight: e.nativeEvent.layout.height });
            }}
             onContentSizeChange={(width, height) => {
               this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo({ y: this.state.scrollHeight });
             }}
          >

Comment: @SumanthU whether refs contains object in web ?